# Are DynamoDB annotation on model are supported through DAX as well?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I Have one model e.g Person representing table Person. I have used @DynamoDBTable,@DynamoDBRangeKey,@DynamoDBAttribute,@DynamoDBHashKey annotations for various get request from the table. can these annotations be used for DAX as well or DAX supports different annotations altogether?

We have setup dynamodb locally but as DAX cannot be set we do not have many options to try.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable{}

@DynamoDBRangeKey
public String getPersonIdfier(){return personIdfier;}
```

Is it possible to use the same annotations of dynamodb for DAX as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the same annotations when using a DAX cluster for two reasons.

1. DAX is API compatible with DynamoDB ([source](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/)).
2. The annotations are actually handled in your DynamoDB client. They are used by `DynamoDBMapper` to convert from a Java object to the proper input to the Rest APIs for DynamoDB. The annotations are never sent over the network. (You can see this for yourself in the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java).)